# A very simple project with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I found this bit of code on the forum and I have been trying for hours to get it
to make it print in another text-field instead of the console...I am trying to create a encrypter...Thanks in advance for the help...

```
from tkinter import *

def print_text():
global e
string = e.get() 
print(string)


root = Tk()

root.title('Name')

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

b = Button(root, text='Okay', command=print_text)
b.pack(side='bottom')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: there is no "other text-field" in your code. There's plenty of documentation for setting the value of various widgets, have you read any of it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a label and a textvariable to that label:

```
from tkinter import *

def print_text():
    global e, l_var
    string = e.get() 
    print(string)
    l_var.set(string)


root = Tk()

root.title('Name')

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

b = Button(root, text='Okay', command=print_text)
b.pack(side='bottom')

l_var = StringVar()
l = Label(root, textvariable=l_var)
l.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

def print_text():
    # global e
    string = e.get() 
    # print(string)
    # updating the label
    l.configure(text=string)

root = Tk()
root.title('Name')

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

b = Button(root, text='Okay', command=print_text)
b.pack(side='bottom')

# a label to display the text from Entry
l = Label(root)
l.pack(side='left')

root.mainloop()
```